# Opencart, always show rating (PHP if, else)

Tags: php, if-statement, opencart

I want to display the rating, even though none is present (show image no rating).

```
<?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>--
```

else show `<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars0.png"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
<?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
<?php } else { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars0.png" /> /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When you hit 15, feel free to come back... ;)